# How to express VB .NET "Aggregate Into" in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a code in VB .NET:

```
Aggregate item In items Into Sum(item.Value)
```

Could someone help me to convert it to C#?

Comment: Whoever voted to close, I don't think a single line of code that's less than 50 characters long is "too localized"...

Comment: Looks like a fancy way of adding a bunch of values together. I would just use an iterator on the collection, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @ginman Why use an iterator? In which way would that be better? One thing, it would be three lines in place of one.

Comment: My comment was more for the sake of argument, and not a real answer. If he is already to the point of asking a question, I am glad he got an accurate answer. However, when approaching code conversion, I think it can be beneficial to qualify what you are doing, rather than just looking for a syntactical equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in C# easily via:

```
var total = items.Sum(item => item.Value);
```

Comment: JRL: actually, this was a thinking process

Comment: @JRL: "vampirized"? That is a new for me. What does that mean?

Comment: @brian: I mean that they both edited their answer to include Reed's one

Comment: @JRL: Hmm...I'm still confused. According to the edit history Kev came in (with the right answer) at 17:33:42z, VVS came in (with the right answer) at 17:34:38z, and Reed came in at 17:35:05z. I'm not seeing any evidence that they plagiarized anything. Are you seeing something different on your screen?

Comment: @Brian: The edit history doesn't show edits within the first couple of minutes (this is a recent change in StackExchange...)  The answers using "Sum" all were added about a minute after I put this up via edits...  Doesn't really matter, but that's what JRL was referring to...

Comment: @Brian: Yeah, it makes it very tough to know who was first - the upside is now you really should focus on which answer is "best" - ie: better written, more clear, etc

Answer (score 3):

```
items.Sum(item => item.Value)
```

I think

You can alway use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ to convert your code, but it's now always reliable.

Comment: Np, useful but not always reliable.

Answer (score 3):

```
items.Aggregate((sum, item) => sum += item.Value);
```

which is the same as:

```
items.Sum(item => item.Value);
```

No need to aggregate.